# save uploaded image names in array using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am using a 3rd party library for uploading files using Ajax and when they have uploaded I want to store the file names in mongoDB.

This is my Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const uploadSchema = new Schema({
    imgName: [{
        type: String
    }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Upload', uploadSchema);
```

I have tried to perform the insert in the success callback for the upload:

```
    if (data.isSuccess) {
     const uploaded = uploader.getFileList();
     for (const images of uploaded) {
        console.log(images.name);
        const upload = new uploadModel({
            imgName: images.name
        });
         upload.save();
     }
```

This is storing each image as in individual record in the database with it's own unique ID which isn't what I want. If I for example upload 2 images, I want it to be one record in the database but should look something like this I guess:

```
_id: ObjectId("123uashjkalh73")
> imgName: Array
  0: "image1.jpg"
  1: "image2.jpg"
__v: 0
```

Answer (score 2):

So I think there are a few things that are off here.

First, in your schema,

```
const uploadSchema = new Schema({
    imgName: [{
        type: String
    }]
});
```

`imgName` is noted set to an Array of objects. If you want an array of strings, you can completely skip the object notation with `type: String` and replace it with `[String]` (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#arrays). I think what you want is the following:

```
const uploadSchema = new Schema({
    imgName: [String]
});
```

If you are trying to create a new model for this, I simplified the code a bit using `reduce`

```
if (data.isSuccess) {
  const uploaded = uploader.getFileList();

  // similar to your loop but i'm just using reduce here. end result is an array of your image names
  const images = uploaded.reduce((acc, image) => [...acc, image.name], []);
  const upload = new uploadModel({
    imgName: images
  });

  upload.save();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for that. It is still inserting individual records per image but I think that is the way the script callback is working. `if (data.isSuccess) {` seems to fire every time an image is uploaded which is why it creates in individual database record for every image.

Comment: @user8463989 ah gotcha, that makes sense. was not able to get that pictured in without seeing the rest of the code. Seems like you're in the right track though.